# Expand container height by multiply value

Tags: jquery, css

I want to expand the height of a container automatically to the multiply of `28px`. I have a pattern that can only be repeated vertically so I can't crop it at a height that is not a multiply of 28. For example if my container has a height of `400px`, I need to expand the height at `420px` so that the pattern repeats vertically and it's not cropped.

Any ideas as to the logic of the jQuery function I need to create?

Comment: @JoshC It will expand fine but the pattern behind it, will crop if the height is not a multiply of 28.

Comment: Both answers below are the solution -- modulus operator `%` gives you the remainder (if any) of a division. So, `$('#mydiv').height() % 28` lets you check to see if the current height is NOT divisible by 28. If not, then you use `Math.ceil` to round up `Math.ceil(height/28) * 28`.

Comment: @Chris I agree with you. Both answers are correct. I wish I could accept them both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this help?

```
var container = $('#container'), unit = 28, height = container.height();
(height % unit > 0) &&
container.height(Math.ceil(height / unit) * unit);
```

Comment: But... it does make the code less explicit. I +1'd, but I would write it closer your way, @PatrickEvans ; easier to debug later because it is more clear.

Comment: @Chris, totally agreed, but I just started writing the code here and didn't use any code editor.

Comment: @HashemQolami Thank you for your answer. Since your answer was the first one, I'll accept yours but Patrick's answer is easier to debug.

Answer (score 4):

```
var needsExpansion = jQuery("#mydiv").height()%28 > 0;
if( needsExpansion ) {
   var newHeight = Math.ceil(jQuery("#mydiv").height()/28) * 28;
   jQuery("#mydiv").height(newHeight);
}
```